# Caret Repeated CV Kappa Doesn't Match Home Coded Foreach Repeated CV Kappa

Tags: r, r-caret, cross-validation

I have been using 10X10-fold cross validation for most of my modeling work, and was hoping that I could simplify my life by having caret do this for me.

However, when I try to run repeated cv in caret, the results seem... odd.

Most notably, the Kappa values are way off what I would expect to see.

- caret repeatedcv kappa = 0.0308791
- home assembled repeated cv kappa = 0.4137178

*(in fairness, the home version uses some function calls from caret, too... but the cross-validation is done explicitly, not embedded within the caret training call)*

This is a big difference.

Any ideas as to what is going on here?

Dataset is located [here](https://github.com/derekrucker/demodata/blob/master/Sample%20Data.csv).

```
# --- Begin caret cv test ---

library(caret)

dataset <- read.csv("Sample Data.csv")

my_control <- trainControl(
  method="repeatedcv",
  number=10,
  repeats = 10,
  savePredictions="final",
  classProbs=TRUE
)

dataset$Temp <- "Yes"
dataset$Temp[which(dataset$Dep.Var=="0")] <- "No"
dataset$Temp <- as.factor(dataset$Temp)

my.formula <- as.formula("Temp ~ Param.F + Param.C")

testmodel <- train(my.formula, data = dataset,
               method = "glm",
               trControl = my_control,
               metric = "Kappa")

# --- End of caret cv test ---
# --- will reference the model "testmodel" later to show comparison
# --- with home built version

# --- Now for the home built version: ---

library(foreach)

out <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .inorder = FALSE) %do% {
  folds <- caret::createFolds(dataset$Temp, k = 10, list = FALSE)

  part.out <- foreach(j = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .inorder = FALSE) %do% {
    deve <- dataset[folds != j, ]
    test <- dataset[folds == j, ]

    temp_model <- glm(my.formula, data=deve, family=binomial(link='logit'))
    pred <- predict(temp_model,newdata=test,type="response")
    data.frame(y = test$Dep.Var, prob = pred)
  }
  part.out
}

c.kappa <- foreach (i = 1:1000, .combine = rbind) %do% {
  pred2 <- as.factor((out$prob>(quantile(out$prob, i/1000)))*1)
  c(quantile(out$prob, i/1000), confusionMatrix(pred2, out$y)$overall[2])
}

pred2 <- as.factor((out$prob>c.kappa[which.max(c.kappa[,2]),1])*1)

# --- End of home built version ---

# --- Now to see the results of each: ---

# --- Home Built ---
caret::confusionMatrix(pred2, out$y)$overall[2]

# --- Caret Repeated CV ---
testmodel$results[3]
```

Comment: Comments in your code would be helpful. I don't see your "homebuilt repeated CV kappa" function,  but perhaps I'm just missing it... a first thought is a idfference in seeds / random sampling.

Comment: @Alex - Added some comments. The difference is repeatable even if you run the code numerous times, suggesting that seeds and random sampling should not play a part. Besides... that is kinda the whole point of running 10X10-fold, isn't it... to run enough variations that any one weird split doesn't skew the result too much.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't set the seed anywhere so none of the resampling results could possibly be confirmed.

If you set the seed just prior to running `train`, you can use the same resampling indices by referencing the `control` object using

```
suffix <- paste0("Rep", gsub(" ", "0", format(1:10)), "$")
out <- foreach(i = 1:10, .combine = rbind, .inorder = FALSE) %do% {
    in_model <- testmodel$control$index[grepl(suffix[i], names(testmodel$control$index))]
```

and then use `in_model[[j]]` to get the data used for modeling and `-in_model[[j]]` gives you the negative integers to derive the same holdout set.

Also, you seem to be assigning the predictions incorrectly. You might want to use something like

```
pred <- predict(temp_model,newdata=test,type="response")
pred <- factor(ifelse(pred > .5, "Yes", "No"))
```

Max

Comment: Thanks for your response! With the number of resampling iterations, I figured that the seed really shouldn't matter. The values were quite repeatable over numerous runs, with different seeds.

Comment: As for the assignment of the predictions, I am choosing the prediction threshold based upon the best Cohen's Kappa, and often that doesn't turn out to be 0.5